# LINQ orderby on date field in descending order

Tags: c#, linq

How can I change the LINQ query in the code below to sort by date in descending order (latest first, earliest last)?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace Helloworld
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            List<Envelops> env = new List<Envelops> ();
            Envelops e = new Envelops { ReportDate = DateTime.Now };
            env.Add (e);
            e = new Envelops { ReportDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays (5) };
            env.Add (e);
            e = new Envelops { ReportDate = new DateTime (2011, 3, 3) };
            env.Add (e);
            e = new Envelops { ReportDate = DateTime.Now };
            env.Add (e);

            foreach (Envelops r in env) {
                Console.WriteLine (  r.ReportDate.ToString("yyyy-MMM"));
            }

            var ud = (from d in env                  
                select  d.ReportDate.ToString("yyyy-MMM") ).Distinct();     

            Console.WriteLine ("After distinct");

            foreach (var r in ud) {
                Console.WriteLine (r);
            }

        }
    }

    class Envelops
    {
        public DateTime ReportDate { get; set; }
    }

}`enter code here`
```

**the current output is:**

```
2011-Apr
2011-May
2011-Mar
2011-Apr
After distinct
2011-Apr
2011-May
2011-Mar
```

I want the output to in the following order:

```
may
april
march order
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I don't believe that Distinct() is guaranteed to maintain the order of the set.

Try pulling out an anonymous type first and distinct/sort on that before you convert to string:

```
var ud = env.Select(d => new 
                         {
                             d.ReportDate.Year,
                             d.ReportDate.Month,
                             FormattedDate = d.ReportDate.ToString("yyyy-MMM")
                         })
            .Distinct()
            .OrderByDescending(d => d.Year)
            .ThenByDescending(d => d.Month)
            .Select(d => d.FormattedDate);
```

Comment: While the question is tagged `linq-to-entities`, the code is using `Enumerable` where `Distinct()` does maintain order. It's still a good idea to do sorting after `Distinct()` to reduce the size of results that need to be sorted, and to be compatible with other linq providers in which `Distinct()` indeed does not guarantee to preserve order

Answer (score 91):

```cs
env.OrderByDescending(x => x.ReportDate)
```

Answer (score 7):

This statement will definitely help you:

```cs
env = env.OrderByDescending(c => c.ReportDate).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to also sort by a DateTime field descending and this seems to do the trick:

```
var ud = (from d in env 
     orderby -d.ReportDate.Ticks                 
     select  d.ReportDate.ToString("yyyy-MMM") ).Distinct();
```

Comment: And that is when I realized the exact purpose of the "s" standard date formatting string, which returns dates formatted to be sortable.