# Linq OrderBy aggregates dates

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I would like to order a list of posts by date of last comment or date of the post.

This is the classes :

```cs
public class Post
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public partial class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateCommented { get; set; }
}
```

The ideal code (whitch don't even compile) would be :

```
IEnumerable <Post> posts = MVPMetroEntities.Posts
                                               .OrderByDescending(p => 
                                                       p.DatePosted || p.Comments.Max(c=>c.DateCommented));
```

Any ideas ? thanks

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813464/linq-orderby-on-date-field-in-descending-order

Comment: `p.DatePosted` is a non-nullable `DateTime`; what are you trying to do by `p.DatePosted || p.Comments.Max(...)` ? if you explain what you are trying to *achieve*, we might be able to help. What does it mean to order by "date of last comment ***or*** date of the post" (emphasis mine)? what does that *mean* ? To put that into context: if I said "order this list of people by their height ***or*** their shoe size" - what does that *mean* ? what would the result be?

Comment: Sorry for this confusion. I mean : Order by DatePost if no comment, or  order by date of last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, with using ternary operator in the OrderByDescending. Thanks :)

```
MVPMetroEntities.Posts
            .OrderByDescending(
                    e => e.Comments.Any() ? e.Comments.Max(f => f.DateCommented) : e.DatePosted)
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are looking for `ThenByDescending`:

```
IEnumerable<Post> posts = MVPMetroEntities.Posts
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.DatePosted)
    .ThenByDescending(p => p.Comments.Max(c => c.DateCommented));
```

Comment: I believe he wants to order post by the most recent comment, then by post date if no comment exists

Comment: ThenByDescending works only if the OrderByDescending has same timestamp, right ?

Comment: @Raph: Yes, similar to a sql-query where you can chain multiple `ORDER BY` separated by comma.

Answer (score 1):

```
var posts = MVPMetroEntities.Posts
                .Select(p => new { 
                     Date = p.Comments.Any() 
                                ? p.Comments.OrderByDescending(c => c.DateCommented).First().Date 
                                : p.DatePosted, 
                     Post = p
                  }
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
```

Comment: Thanks for the ternary operator idea, i will use it directly in "OrderBy"

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your intention clearly, but how about this

```
MVPMetroEntities.Posts
.OrderByDescending(p => Recent(p.DatePosted, p.Comments.Max(c => c.DateCommented)));
```

by using a helper method/extension methods like this

```
        public DateTime Recent(DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2)
        {
            return dt1 > dt2 ? dt1 : dt2;
        }
```

Note: helper may not work if you are using any ORM like Linq-to-sql