# C# Sort list Box by Date in list entry Name

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox, directoryinfo

I have a ListBox, filled by DirectoryInfo:

```
FileInfo[] files = (new DirectoryInfo(Program.pathtofiles())).GetFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)files.Length; i++)
            {
                FileInfo fileName = files[i];
                this.ListBox.Items.Add(fileName);
            }
```

one Item looks like:

> DATA_department_08-09-2017.pdf

So my Question is how to sort the Itmes in the ListBox by the Date at the end? I know there are some sort-functions for the ListBox but they don´t work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the file-name contains three tokens and the last is the date, you can use this LINQ approach:

```
var sortedPaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Program.pathtofiles())
    .Select(Path => new { Path, Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path) })
    .Select(x => new { x.Path, Date = DateTime.Parse(x.Name.Split('_').Last()) })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
    .Select(x => x.Path);
```

If you want to reorder the list-items without reading from file-system:

```
var sortedPaths = this.ListBox.Items.Cast<string>()
    .Select(Path => new { Path, Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path) })
    .Select(x => new { x.Path, Date = DateTime.Parse(x.Name.Split('_').Last()) })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
    .Select(x => x.Path);
this.ListBox.Items.AddRange(sortedPaths.ToArray());
```

If you want last dates first use `OrderByDescending`.

Comment: `var sortedPaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Program.pathtofiles())
    .Select(Path => new { Path, Name = Path.**GetFileNameWithoutExtension**(Path) })
    .Select(x => new { x.Path, Date = DateTime.Parse(x.Name.Split('_').Last()) })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
    .Select(x => x.Path);` How to get the file name without Extentsion?

Comment: @Scrober: the method is in the `Path`-class which is in the `System.IO` namespace, just google ;-)
So you can also write(without `using System.IO`): `Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path)`

Comment: Okay, at first my Visual Basic does not find this command und the using System.IO.Path is also not avaiable but with System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension everything works just fine

Comment: okay some times the end ist like "08-09-2017(1)" and sometimes there is a name like "DATA_08-09-2017(4).pdf"  so i think it will not handle everything from the pas exactly but everything from the Future. :) Thanks a Lot

Comment: @Scrober: if you want to ignore the part after the date you can remove it: `DateTime.Parse(x.Name.Split('(')[0].Split('_').Last())`

Answer (score 0):

The filenames are just strings but you could try to parse the filename into a custom class with a datetime field and the filename as property. You have to cut the date part from the filename and parse it into a real datetime type

Then you can use linq to order the list of files like mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5813530/4318778