# ListBox sorting by files creation time

Tags: c#

My listBox1 is filled with names of txt files. It is sorting them automatically alphabetically. But I need to sort these files by creation time, from the newest to the oldest. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you please share your code while asking a question? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried basically nothing. I tried to google it but didnt find anything.

Comment: [File.GetCreationTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getcreationtime?view=netframework-4.8) or [File.GetCreationTimeUtc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getcreationtimeutc?view=netframework-4.8) may help (System.IO namespace)

Comment: _I tried to google it but didnt find anything_  just found this using first google link [C# Sort list Box by Date in list entry Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113212/c-sharp-sort-list-box-by-date-in-list-entry-name), as well as many others

Comment: Please share the code you have so far, even if it doesn't relate to sorting by create date. It's impossible for us to advise you on how to sort these files without seeing any code at all. We need to see how you get the list of files, how you put them into the `ListBox`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you are not giving us much to go on :P

But I am going to give it my best shot to help you. Because I do not know how you have populated the List (by hand, or with code) I cant really guide you there.

But lets say you did it by code. The following snippet I typed might help you find what you need

```
//array of file names (these need to be paths to files, so if you do not prefix it with ./path/ or anything, then the executable needs to be in the same folder)
//If you are debugging, make sure the paths are correct if you expect them to be in the same folder, it should then be in the debug folder.
//If you included some test files in the solution and want them copied to your debug folder. Click on them, go to the properties pane, and set build action to content, and one of the other properties should read copy of newer instead of never copy
var fileNames = new string[]{"1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt"};

var fileInfos = fileNames.Select(f => new FileInfo(f));

var orderedFileInfos = fileInfos.OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime);
```

orderedFileInfos is now a list of type FileInfo ordered by ascending on their creationtime.

This is what you can use to populate your ListBox

I hope i helped you progress in your project.